# Hibernate: Problem with mapping

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem with hibernate. (((

**[!!! Image with Database Schema !!!](http://img12.imageshost.ru/img/2011/06/19/image_4dfdbd74a9911.png)**

**Mapping
(for getter's/setter's i use lombok)**

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public @Data class User
{

// Base Mapping

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
@Getter @Setter Long user_id;   

@Column(name = "user_name")
private @Getter @Setter String user_name;

@Column(name = "login")
private @Getter @Setter String login;

@Column(name = "password")
private @Getter @Setter String password;

// Releations Mapping

// Releations With Project

@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinTable(name="users_on_projects",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id") )
        private @Getter @Setter  List<Project>  projects = new Vector();


@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="intervals",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="users_on_projects_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="interval_id") )
        private  @Getter @Setter List<Interval> intervals = new Vector();
}
```

**Project.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public @Data class Project
{

// Base Mapping

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name ="project_id")
private @Getter @Setter  Long project_id;

@Column(name ="project_name")
private @Getter @Setter String project_name;


// Releations Mapping

// Releations With User

  @ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinTable(name="users_on_projects",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id") )
  private @Getter @Setter  List<User>  users = new Vector();

@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name="intervals",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="users_on_projects_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="interval_id") )
        private  @Getter @Setter List<Interval> intervals = new Vector();
}
```

**Interval.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "intervals")
public class Interval
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "interval_id")
@Getter @Setter Long interval_id;

@Column(name ="start_time")
private @Setter @Getter 
            @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
            Date start_time;

@Column(name ="finish_time")
private @Setter @Getter 
        @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        Date FinishTime;


@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}) 
@JoinTable(name="users_on_projects",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="users_on_projects_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id") )
        private  @Getter @Setter User user;


@JoinTable(name="users_on_projects",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="users_on_projects_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id") )
        private  @Getter @Setter 
@ManyToOne
         Project project;


@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="interval_type_id")
private  @Getter @Setter IntervalType intervalType;

}
```

**IntervalType.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "interval_type")
public class IntervalType
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "interval_type_id")
@Getter @Setter Long interval_type_id;

@Column(name = "interval_type_name")
private @Getter @Setter String interval_type_name;
}
```

I can read any data from any table, but cannot write into intervals table ((

The error message is:
    *Field 'users_on_projects_id' doesn't have a default value*
And hibernate generate this SQL code: 
    insert into intervals (finish_time, interval_type_id, start_time) values (?, ?, ?)

What's wrong with mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping looks a bit strange (but may I understand is wrong). What I found so strange is that both relations:

- User -> Interval
- Project -> Interval

are stored in the SAME join table "intervals" and in both cases the one case the JoinColumn is "users_on_projects_id".

For my it looks like a copy and past bug.

Comment: So, what is the correct mapping should I use for this database : 

http://img12.imageshost.ru/img/2011/06/19/image_4dfdbd74a9911.png

?

Comment: @anonymous: first remove the relations between intervall and project, and then have a look at so called ternery associations: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-ternary